# sqlCommand object and adding parameters using loop

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

We can clear all the text boxes in a form using foreach without typing codes for each text box to clear them.

```
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@",objPlayrInjr_P));

using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
{
    com.CommandText = "SPname";
    com.Connection = connection object;
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SqlParameterName",objectName.propertyName));
}
```

I need a method to add `sqlParameters` to the `Command` object through a loop, like how I did when clearing text boxes. So no need to write code for each and every statement, it will be done by the loop.

Comment: to go through a loop, you need a list of parameter names and property values.

Comment: I would recommend just using a standard approach to adding parameters. Keep them in the data layer/classes. I do not think you will get much of a time saving from trying to supply a list of parameters in or marking up your domain objects with parameter names.

Comment: My first question is what have you tried?  Please show code examples of what you have attempted.  If you haven't tried anything - then please use "The Google" to assist you.  We are all more than happy to help - but please "Help us help you".

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to put your parameter names and values in a `Dictionary<string, object>` and then

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> param in params)
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.Key, param.Value);
}
```

Comment: Would you recommend doing this though? Your form model would consist entirely of a Dictionary of arbitrary values.

Comment: What form model?  There's no context given for the problem, other than he wants to be able to set SqlParameter's in a loop.  The only reference to "form" is that one can use a foreach on a form to clear text boxes.  I do exactly this when setting up complex queries based on user input (e.g. user can select 1..N keys that become part of an IN clause).

Answer (score 3):

Here is something using annotations:

### Annotation for marking a property with parameter name

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ParameterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ParameterName { get; private set; }

    public ParameterAttribute(string parameterName)
    {
        ParameterName = parameterName;
    }
}
```

### Example class

```
public class Person
{
    [Parameter("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Parameter("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Parameter("EmailAddress")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

### Usage

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

Person person = new Person()
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Email = "johndoe@domain.com"
};

foreach (var pi in person.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var attribute = (ParameterAttribute)pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ParameterAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();

    if (attribute != null)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@{0}", attribute.ParameterName), pi.GetValue(person, null));
    }
}
```